# Struct with a member that is the struct itself

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member

I have a struct with several members and one of them is the same struct itself. What I want to do is have a pointer to a struct related to that same struct but is of the same type. The compiler does not recognize the type when reading the struct members since it is still to be defined. Is there any alternative way to do what I want to happen?

```
typedef struct _panels
{
    int id;
    // Dimensions
    double length;
    double height;

    // Global coordinates of origin of LCS
    double origX;
    double origY;
    double origZ;

    // Orientation of local x-axis wrt global X-axis
    double angle;

    // Panel reinforcement
    int nReinforcement;
    double *xReinf; // arbitrary spacing
    double sx;  // fixed spacing
    double xReinf0; // x-coordinate of first rebar

    // CHB unit
    CHBUnit *chb;

    // Openings
    int nOpenings;
    CHBOpening *openings;

    // Pointer to adjacent panels
    CHBPanel * left;    int leftPanelID;
    CHBPanel * right;   int rightPanelID;
}CHBPanel;
```

Comment: "I have a struct with several members and one of them is the same struct itself." No, you don't. It cannot be made because it will consume infinite amount of memory.

Comment: note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace. You shouldn't pollute their namespace. For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the compiler.

Comment: This declaration will invoke *undefined behavior* if this is global. Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the defined (incomplete in the definition of the structure) type `struct _panels` instead of `CHBPanel`, which is not defined yet, to declare pointers to the structure itself.

The last part

```
    CHBPanel * left;    int leftPanelID;
    CHBPanel * right;   int rightPanelID;
```

should be

```
    struct _panels * left;    int leftPanelID;
    struct _panels * right;   int rightPanelID;
```

Alternative way: You can do the `typedef` before the declaration of the structure.

```
typedef struct _panels CHBPanel;
struct _panels
{
    int id;

    /* snipped */

    // Pointer to adjacent panels
    CHBPanel * left;    int leftPanelID;
    CHBPanel * right;   int rightPanelID;
};
```